# collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status for

Tags: c, makefile, patch

I am trying to use two github repositories as shown below:

https://github.com/markoneill/ssa-daemon

https://github.com/markoneill/ssa

When trying to execute "build-client-auth.sh" in the ssa-daemon directory I ran into this error. Also, in order to make it easy to troubleshoot I went into "build-client-auth.sh" and took the command on line 72 that was giving me an error, which is "make clientauth" as shown below.

```
[eli@localhost ssa-daemon]$ make clientauth

make -C ./qrdisplay

make[1]: Entering directory '/home/eli/csci400/ssa-daemon/qrdisplay'


make[1]: 'bin/qrPopUp' is up to date.

make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/eli/csci400/ssa-daemon/qrdisplay'

gcc hashmap.o netlink.o hashmap_str.o tls_wrapper.o config.o issue_cert.o 

daemon.o main.o self_sign.o openssl_compat.o csr_daemon.o rfcomm_client.o nsd.o 

log.o rfcomm_server.o queue.o notification.o tb_connector.o auth_daemon.o -o 

tls_wrapper -Llibevent/lib -Lopenssl/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,libevent/lib -Wl,-rpath 

-Wl,openssl/lib -lpthread pkg-config --libs libconfig libevent_openssl libnl-

genl-3.0 libnotify avahi-client openssl

/usr/bin/ld: rfcomm_client.o: in function main': /home/eli/csci400/ssa-

daemon/rfcomm_client.c:35: multiple definition of main'; 

main.o:/home/eli/csci400/ssa-daemon/main.c:61: first defined here

/usr/bin/ld: rfcomm_server.o: in function main': /home/eli/csci400/ssa-

daemon/rfcomm_server.c:15: multiple definition of main'; 

main.o:/home/eli/csci400/ssa-daemon/main.c:61: first defined here

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make: *** [Makefile:65: clientauth] Error 1
```

---

Thanks to Kuchara, who said to remove both rfcomm_client.c and rfcomm_server.c, I was able to get passed the error above. However, I am getting a new error as follows:

Done

Building custom sslsplit

Cloning into 'sslsplit'...

remote: Enumerating objects: 155, done.

remote: Counting objects: 100% (155/155), done.

remote: Compressing objects: 100% (110/110), done.

remote: Total 4050 (delta 80), reused 106 (delta 43), pack-reused 3895

Receiving objects: 100% (4050/4050), 1.59 MiB | 4.92 MiB/s, done.

Resolving deltas: 100% (2885/2885), done.

0001-SSA-patch.patch:147: trailing whitespace.

error: patch failed: pxyconn.c:936

error: pxyconn.c: patch does not apply

===========================================================================

## So, what I did was look at the build script for the section that was making the error and saw this:

echo "Building custom sslsplit"

git clone https://github.com/droe/sslsplit

cd sslsplit

cp ../extras/sslsplit/0001-SSA-patch.patch .

cp ../extras/sslsplit/ca.crt .

cp ../extras/sslsplit/ca.key .

cp ../extras/sslsplit/start.sh .

cp ../extras/sslsplit/firewallOn.sh .

git apply 0001-SSA-patch.patch

make

cd ..

echo "Done"

**So, what I believe is the "git apply 0001-SSA-patch.patch" is giving the error, but how I would I fix it?**

Comment: If you read through the error messages it's quite clear what the error is: `multiple definition of main'`. That means you have *two* `main` functions in your code. You should only have one. Are you trying to link the code of two different programs into a single executable?

Comment: You are attempting to link rfcomm_client.o and rfcomm_server.o together.  They are probably intended to be kept separate.

Comment: I am trying to replicate a paper for using SSA and TLS as an operating system and the sources are proved to me from the github links I have posted above. You need both ssa and ssa-daemon in order to run this service. However, I am stuck with trying to execute the build script inside the ssa-daemon directory. So, overall I am just running what I get from the the two repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out this revision: 6955368275b4372ebd0b7a125de626808a7e5aef

According to the git log, problematic files seem to be some test codes, which were added recently:
https://github.com/markoneill/ssa-daemon/commit/d5a94cb4409dd27e4478b4bba2413dfae1c70169

BTW that failure you have is the reason why I usually discourage to use wildcards. :-)

Comment: I tried to Add the new bluetooth client and server test files, but I still got the same error.

Comment: Try to *not* add test files. Remove rfcomm_client.c and rfcomm_server.c, and try running build script.

Comment: Thank you Kuchara, It worked, but I ran into another error. I added it below the previous error I was having.

Comment: Seems you try to use project (ssa-daemon) which is not maintained actively. I propose you three ways: 1) (easiest) wait until your issue on GitHub is solved by repo maintainer; 2) (easy) try to checkout versions of all repositories' revisions close to Oct 5;  3) or alternatively, you can try to manually rebase 0001-SSA-patch.patch (that is: look what changes it introduce, and try to apply them manually). This is all I could advice you here.

Comment: The repo maintainer is very inactive and I am sure I downloaded the latest version with the git clone command, unless there is a more proper way. Also, do you know where I can find information about the patch "0001-SSA-patch.patch" or download it?

Answer (score 0):

the patch was not working so I applied the patch by hand and it works!